# What are block container boxes in the visual formatting model?

Tags: css

I'm trying to understand **block container boxes** as described in the CSS2.1 spec, but I'm having a tough go of it. The spec doesn't really provide a definition. They just say that:

> A block container box either contains only block-level boxes or establishes an inline formatting context and thus contains only inline-level boxes.

Also according to the spec, all non-replaced block-level boxes (except table boxes) are block containers boxes. Thus, body, div, p, etc. are all block containers boxes.

Under anonymous block boxes:

> If a block container box has a block-level box inside it, then we force it to have *only* block-level boxes inside it.

Thus, in the example:

```
<div>
  Some text
  <p>More text</p>
</div>
```

"Some text" is in an anonymous block box.

OK, that works, but when I try this example:

```
<div>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <em>Emphasized text</em>
  <em>More emphasized text</em>
  More regular text.
</div>
```

It displays as:

```
  Some text.

  _Emphasized text_ _More emphasized text_ More regular text.
```

Whereas I would have expected

```
  Some text.

  _Emphasized text_

  _More emphasized text_

  More regular text.
```

In other words, the em elements and the anonymous fragment ("More regular text") are behaving as inline-level boxes, apparently contradicting the statement "If a block container box has a block-level box inside it, then we force it to have *only* block-level boxes inside it." It also contradicts the statement that block containers can only have all block-level boxes or all inline-level boxes, because the "Some text" in the paragraph element is behaving as a block-level box.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I observe that if the first example can create an anonymous block round the text, there is no obvious reason why the second should not create an anonymous block round the text and the in-line elements.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`<p>` is already a block level element, so it treats it as such.  Everything else inside the `<div>` is also treated as a (single) block level element.  The specification doesn't say that **each** individual element will be treated as an individual block level element.  Only that it will treat everything inside as block-level elements.

Therefore in your example

```
  <em>Emphasized text</em>
  <em>More emphasized text</em>
  More regular text.
```

This is all treated as a single block level element with multiple in-line elements inside it.  Which fits with the specification.

Note that you can control this behavior by explicitly doing this:

```
  <div>
    <em>Emphasized text</em>
    <em>More emphasized text</em>
    More regular text.
  </div>
```

Or for the result you expected you can do this:

```
  <div><em>Emphasized text</em></div>
  <div><em>More emphasized text</em></div>
  <div>More regular text.</div>
```